# Empty strings in c# Class

Tags: c#

I have a class which contains this:

```
public long dogNumber { get; set; }
public long catNumber { get; set; }
public long dogName { get; set; }
```

And this is how i populate it:

```
var lunder = new List<herdig>();
foreach (string labl in liste) 
{
    string[] lab = labl.Split('!');
    var herdig = new herdig
    {
        dogNumber = long.Parse(lab[0]),
        catNumber  = long.Parse(lab[1]),
        dogName = lab[2]
    }
    lunder.Add(herdig);
}
```

My problem is that sometimes lab[2] is empty, and using this i get an error if i dont populate all. How can i fix this?

Thank you:)

Comment: Can you put something like checking length of lab list before actually accessing this through index? It will be like `if len(list) >1, do something with lab[2]; otherwise, ignore lab[2];`

Comment: Is it _empty_ or does `lab` only have two elements?

Comment: do you mean it throws out of bounds array exception or parse exception? what is the exact error you get?

Comment: `dogName` is of type `long`?

Comment: Can you post an example of what content is in `liste`?

Comment: @LukasKabrt todays people give their dogs a number name. the world is changed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want handle possible errors from this process you can do this.

```
foreach (string labl in liste)
{
    string[] lab = labl.Split('!');

    long dog, cat;

    int len = lab.Length;

    long.TryParse(len > 0 ? lab[0] : "0", out dog);
    long.TryParse(len > 1 ? lab[1] : "0", out cat);

    var herdig = new herdig
    {
        dogNumber = dog,
        catNumber = cat,
        dogName = len > 2 ? lab[2] : "" // this is string.
    };

    lunder.Add(herdig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was the `long.Parse` and not what I first thought. Yhanks for the comments though, it helped me figure it out :)